# Android Studio, uiautomator and Windows failed to connect to socket 'tcp:9008':

Tags: python, windows, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to run test with uiautomator and android studio emulator on Windows machine.
It's worth to remind that I'm running the same set up and test on MacOS and everything works fine.
I was debugging the peace of code for example:

```
from uiautomator import device as d
d.screen.off() # -> on this step program starts infinitely running
```

In PyCharm, no errors appeared, so I decided to use `adb logcat` to check what was happening.
As a result:

```
android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied 
ActivityManager: Failure reporting to instrumentation watcher: comp=ComponentInfo{com.github.uiautomator.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} results=Bundle[{id=ActivityManagerService, Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.github.uiautomator.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}}]
382   382 E adbd    : failed to connect to socket 'tcp:9008': Connection refused
```

Adb server works and I was able to reboot the phone from adb commands.
Adb sees that device is attached.

Set up:
Phone Emulator: Pixel 3, API 30, R
Env variables $ANDROID_HOME$, sdk-tools as well
Installed the latest Java version
uiautomator==1.0.2

I tried to restart the adb server with

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Also with

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Killed all processes with 5037

```
netstat -ano | findstr "5037"
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

Checked firewall settings and allowed adb to use public and private
Shutted down Windows Defender